# Delte record from db

Tags: php

Can i delete a record using the following function? If yes how can i do this? I have to pass the function to the submit button?

```
function deleteImage($id = "")
        {
            if(isset($_POST['delete_image']))
            {
                $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM store WHERE id='$id'");
            }
               return $query;

        }
```

the html looks like this:

```
<?php

   $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) {
?>
        <form action="admin.php" method="post">
            <?php 
                echo "<img src=".$row['image'].">"; 
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="delete_image" value="DELETE IMAGE">
        </form>
<?php       
   }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not re-post.

Comment: i changed the description because i want to make myself clear. sorry for posting again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this , add hidden input in form inside while loop.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"
```

Then in action.php file

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
if(isset($_POST['delete_image']))
{
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM store WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete_image']))
    {
        $query = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM store WHERE id='".$_POST['image_id']."'")or die(mysqli_error());
    }

    $images = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM store");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($images)) 
    {
?>
        <form action="admin.php" method="post">
            <?php echo "<img src=".$row['image'].">"; ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="image_id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="image_id"/>
            <input type="submit" name="delete_image" value="DELETE IMAGE">
        </form>
<?php       
    }
?>
```

I passed image id in hidden field.

Comment: You are aware that your suggestion is widely open for sql injection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Answer (score 0):

This your view

```
<td>    
<?php $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store"); ?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="deleting[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_from_database'] ?>">
<?php endwhile; ?>
<input type="submit" name="delete_image" value="DELETE IMAGE">
</form>
</td>
```

This your code

```
<?php
function deleteImage()
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete_image'], $_POST['deleting']) && !empty($_POST['deleting']))
    {
        $ids = array_map('intval', $_POST['deleting']); // Type conversion to integer
        $ids = implode(', ', $ids); // Bringing to id1,id2...
        $query = mysql_query('DELETE FROM images WHERE id IN(' . $ids . ')'); // Deleting
        return (bool)$query;
    }
}
?>
```

Now you need set checkbox which images you want to delete and press submit.